# Moq.Object is null still VS shows its fields

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

VS 2012, .NET 4.0, Moq.4.1.1308.2321, Debug configuration.
My static class creates Moq object like this:

```
public static Mock<IQuoteStorage> MakeMoq()
{
    var moq = new Mock<IQuoteStorage>();
    moq.Setup(s => s.GetTickersHistoryStarts()).Returns<Dictionary<string, DateSpan>>(
        delegate
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, DateSpan>();                        
        });

    moq.Setup(s => s.GetMinuteCandlesPacked(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>())).Returns((string ticker, DateTime start, DateTime end) =>
        {
            return new PackedCandleStream(new List<CandleDataPacked>(), false);                      
        });

    return moq;            
}
```

I store this MakeMoq().Object in a static variable **implementer** of a class named QuoteStorageProxy. Then I use this QuoteStorageProxy - make an instance of it and call some method. In this method I check

```
if (implementer == null) // ReferenceEquals do the same
    throw new Exception("...");
```

I do not see any reason for the **implementer** (Moq.Object) being null. VS debugger shows its fields! In **Immediate** I check "implementer == null" and get false. Still I get the exception!

How can it be null and not null at the same time?

Comment: Can you share the (relevant) code for `QuoteStorageProxy`? Do you reset the variable at some point? What is Immediate?

Comment: Another note: Are we talking about a unit test environment? If so it seems to have a lot of test logic in it! Might you be in need for unit tests for your unit tests?

Comment: Is this really related to Moq? You have a property `MakeMoq().Object` which is not a null reference (did you check this?). Then you assign this to a `static` field, `implementer = MakeMoq().Object;`. Is `QuoteStorageProxy.implementer` null just after the assignment? If `implementer` is later null, someone must have assigned null to it.